# Transition come back to original state smoothly

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-transitions

I made a CSS3 tansition on a `<div>` which is suposed to toggle on click. I managed to make the transition I want on the even clicks (with the help of jQuery `.toggleClass`) but I can't figure out how to come back to the original state smoothly.

This means, I need (on odd click events) the`div` to **rotate back** to normal and then **come back to position** (with the `top` property). All this as **smooth** as the even click animation.

Here is a **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/7RYk3/9/)**

And my code :

HTML :

```
<div></div>
```

CSS :

```
  div {
    width:300px;
    height:100px;
    border-radius:2px;
    background:gold;
    position:absolute;
    left:40px;
    top:50%;
    margin-top:-1px;
}
div.anim {
    top:30%;
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1000, 45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 45deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1000, 45deg);
    -webkit-transition: top 0.5s ease-out, transform 0.5s ease-out 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: top 0.5s ease-out, transform 0.5s ease-out 0.5s;
    transition: top 0.5s ease-out, transform 0.5s ease-out 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: top 0.5s ease-out, -webkit-transform 0.5s ease-out 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: top 0.5s ease-out, -webkit-transform 0.5s ease-out 0.25s;
    transition: top 0.5s ease-out, -webkit-transform 0.5s ease-out 0.25s;
}
```

JS :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('div').click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('anim');
    });

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution to make the animation reverse :

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/7RYk3/13/)**

CSS :

```
div {
    width:300px;
    height:100px;
    border-radius:2px;
    background:gold;
    position:absolute;
    left:40px;
    top:50%;
    margin-top:-1px;
    -webkit-transition: top 0.5s ease-out 0.5s, -webkit-transform 0.5s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: top 0.5s ease-out 0.5s, -moz-transform 0.5s ease-out;
    transition: top 0.5s ease-out 0.5s, transform 0.5s ease-out;
}
div.anim {
    -webkit-transition: top 0.5s ease-out, -webkit-transform 0.5s ease-out 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: top 0.5s ease-out, -moz-transform 0.5s ease-out 0.25s;
    transition: top 0.5s ease-out, transform 0.5s ease-out 0.25s;

    top:30%;
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1000, 45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 45deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1000, 45deg);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Put the transition in the base element. Also, you have duplicate transition statements, I'm not sure which you want but the latter will override the former

```
div {
    /* ... Other properties ...*/
    -webkit-transition: top 0.5s ease-out, -webkit-transform 0.5s ease-out 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: top 0.5s ease-out, -moz-transform 0.5s ease-out 0.25s;
    transition: top 0.5s ease-out, transform 0.5s ease-out 0.25s;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/7RYk3/10/)

Comment: The problem is that with this solution, the div (on odd click) starts by moving back, I need it to rotate first then move is this possible?